# What is this key management scheme called

Tags: encryption, key-management, aes

We are building a system, where the messages between services is encrypted with *Data Encryption Key (DEK)*.

The *DEK* is attached to the message, but encrypted with another key, *Key Encryption Key (KEK)*. This way it's easy to rotate *DEK's* or even generate new one for every message, where as *KEK's* are rotated considerably less frequently. *KEK's* are distributed between the participating systems in advance. *KEK's* may be also rotated, which requires each service to re-encrypt all stored *DEK's* with the new *KEK*.

Is there a name for this scheme? I'm trying to search for more information and concrete examples about the approach, but there seems to be very limited amount of information available. Where I can find more information about this scheme?